# Binomial expansion of modulus?

Tags: binomial-theorem

How one can perform binomial expansion of modulus of a quantity. 
For example, can we expand |-1+x| ? If, yes how?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

start with squaring the expression because the square of any expression is positive $$\left(\vert -1+x\vert^{2}\right)^{n}=\left(-1+x\right)^{2n}.$$ Now you may use the normal binomial theorem to expand.

let $m=2n$ then expand $$\left(-1+x\right)^{m}.$$ Re substitute the $2n$ back after expansion.

Answer (score 1):

Two cases it depends on (-1+x) value

Case 1: (-1+x) is positive then write  it as $(x-1)^n$ and use normal binomial theorem

Case 2: if (-1+x) is negative your answer is $-(x-1)^n$

Again if n is not a positive integer then you have to use

$$(1+x)^n=1+nx+ \frac{n(n-1)}{1 \cdot 2} x^2 + \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{1\cdot2\cdot3} x^3+\cdots$$

So then case 1 will be $$(-1)^n \bigg[\frac{n(n-1)}{1 \cdot 2}x^2 + \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{1\cdot2\cdot3} x^3+ \cdots \bigg]$$

Case 2 will be $$(-1)^{n+1}\bigg[1+nx+ \frac{n(n-1)}{1 \cdot 2}x^2 + \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{1\cdot2\cdot3} x^3+ \cdots\bigg]$$

Comment: Is it true for all such cases?

Comment: Yes, I've got it. Thanks.